# MySQL for Visual Studio Plugin with DARK color theme

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, themes

I tried to use MySQL for Visual Studio (2015) Plugin with the DARK color theme and encountered a problem:

[image: DARK color theme query editor]

[image: BLUE color theme query editor]

How can I change text colors to use DARK theme and see the query clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Visual Studio 2019 (this might be the same in older versions too) you can go to Tools > Options... Then in the categories on left side go Environment > Fonts and Colors.

With *Show Settings for:* set to *Text Editor* you can scroll down in the *Display Items* list and find various entries that start with *MySQL*. You can edit those to change foreground color.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. There is no such thing like a MySQL Workbench plugin for Visual Studio. What you are using is the "MySQL for Visual Studio Plugin" (M4VS).
2. The colors are what is set for syntax highlighting. I'm not aware of a way to change them dynamically. In MySQL Workbench there is an xml file that configures the colors, but I don't know if such a thing exists for M4VS (I doubt it).